# mapreduce.Job: Job failed with state FAILED due to: Application failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_exited with exitCode: 1

Tags: docker, hadoop

I configured hadoop and run it on Docker. The problem in the title confused me a lot. Details are below.

I referred to the tutorial

```
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainerExecutor.html
```

and ran a wordcount example.

```
./hadoop namenode -format
./start-yarn.sh
./start-dfs.sh
./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver

hdfs dfs -mkdir -p input
echo "hello world" > file.txt
hdfs dfs -put file.txt input

hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount -Dmapreduce.map.env="yarn.nodemanager.docker-container-executor.image-name=sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.4.1" -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.env="yarn.nodemanager.docker-container-executor.image-name=sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.4.1" -Dmapreduce.reduce.env="yarn.nodemanager.docker-container-executor.image-name=sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.4.1" input output
```

Then the logs showed in the image:
[image: logs in the master node]

and the nodemanager automatically pulled a sequence/spark:1.6.0 image when running this emample. 
[image: docker images in a slave node]
I have no idea what happened.

Then I looked at the syslog in logs/userlogs/.
[image: syslog in the slave node]
and no userlogs in the master node.

As a matter of fact, the safemode was always OFF.

This is a pretty weird problem. Any advice and solution will be appreciated!